# Legitimacy of putting tests in src folder for projects bootstrapped by create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, frontend, create-react-app

I'm a beginner at front end development and have just started to use create-react-app for bootstraping my project. I understand that CRA uses jest and have limited jest to only find tests within the `src` folder. As referenced [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/bce2bfca6d33ad10c77e815db8265f1ed9286881/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js#L40).

Since files in `src` are transpiled and processed by webpack(referencing [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#folder-structure)) when running `npm run build`, does it mean that the tests would be transpiled into the `build` folder as well?

If so, is that considered appropriate to deploy the build that includes tests as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack will only bundle files that are referenced in the dependency tree, starting from the `entry` file specified. Take a look at the [development config](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/bce2bfca6d33ad10c77e815db8265f1ed9286881/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L87) and [production config](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/bce2bfca6d33ad10c77e815db8265f1ed9286881/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L115).

Usually, bundles only include source code, not tests.  Generally, the end user wants to run the program, not verify it.

So if you do see spec files in your bundle, then they have been included in the dependency tree somewhere.